# Spring MVC Annotated Controller Interface with @PathVariable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Is there any reason not to map Controllers as interfaces?

In all the examples and questions I see surrounding controllers, all are concrete classes. Is there a reason for this? I would like to separate the request mappings from the implementation. I hit a wall though when I tried to get a `@PathVariable` as a parameter in my concrete class.

My Controller interface looks like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/services/goal/")
public interface GoalService {

    @RequestMapping("options/")
    @ResponseBody
    Map<String, Long> getGoals();

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}/", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseBody
    void removeGoal(@PathVariable String id);

}
```

And the implementing class:

```
@Component
public class GoalServiceImpl implements GoalService {

    /* init code */

    public Map<String, Long> getGoals() {
        /* method code */
        return map;
    }

    public void removeGoal(String id) {
        Goal goal = goalDao.findByPrimaryKey(Long.parseLong(id));
        goalDao.remove(goal);
    }

}
```

The `getGoals()` method works great; the `removeGoal(String id)` throws an exception

```
ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void
    todo.webapp.controllers.services.GoalServiceImpl.removeGoal(java.lang.String)]: 
    org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required 
    String parameter 'id' is not present
```

If I add the `@PathVariable` annotation to the concrete class everything works as expected, but why should i have to re-declare this in the concrete class? Shouldn't it be handled by whatever has the `@Controller` annotation?

Comment: Looks like I just didn't understand annotation inheritance, i'll post my explanation after I wait for my 8 hour timeout to expire

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Apparently, when a request pattern is mapped to a method via the `@RequestMapping` annotation, it is mapped to to the concrete method implementation. So a request that matches the declaration will invoke `GoalServiceImpl.removeGoal()` directly rather than the method that originally declared the `@RequestMapping` ie `GoalService.removeGoal()`.

Since an annotation on an interface, interface method, or *interface method parameter* does not carry over to the implementation there is no way for Spring MVC to recognize this as a `@PathVariable` unless the implementing class declares it explicitly. Without it, any AOP advice that targets `@PathVariable` parameters will not be executed.

Comment: To be clear, there's no reason Spring MVC couldn't have done this.  It works fine in Jersey.  But they chose not to for whatever reason.

Comment: full support for annotations on interfaces got added recently - please see my answer below and upvote

Answer (score 17):

**The feature of defining all bindings on interface actually got implement recently in Spring 5.1.5.**

Please see this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/15682 - it was a struggle :)

Now you can actually do:

```
@RequestMapping("/random")
public interface RandomDataController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{type}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    RandomData getRandomData(
            @PathVariable(value = "type") RandomDataType type, @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false, defaultValue = "10") int size);
}
```

```
@Controller
public class RandomDataImpl implements RandomDataController {

    @Autowired
    private RandomGenerator randomGenerator;

    @Override
    public RandomData getPathParamRandomData(RandomDataType type, int size) {
        return randomGenerator.generateRandomData(type, size);
    }
}
```

You can even use this library: https://github.com/ggeorgovassilis/spring-rest-invoker

To get a client-proxy based on that interface, similarly to how RestEasys client framework works in the JAX-RS land.

Answer (score 10):

It works in newer version of Spring.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
public interface TestApi {
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test();
}
```

Implement the interface in the Controller

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class TestApiController implements TestApi {

    @Override
    public String test() {
        log.info("In Test");
        return "Value";
    }

}
```

It can be used as:
[Rest client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBcCF.png)

Comment: Have you tested this with annotated parameters?

Comment: @Sabuh Das what version are you using ?

Comment: spring 4.3.* works. But there is no params in this example. spring-mvc handler adapters are not aware of any annotated params in interface method. And there is some workaround: Interface method with spring-mvc annotations can have default implementation. This implementation delegates call to another _abstract_ method, which is implemented by class with `@RestController` annotation. In this scenario spring binds http request handler to interface method with default implementation. [See simple example](https://gist.github.com/milovtim/d90e4aed64860658479423235e4fac97#file-democontroller-java)

Comment: @TimurMilovanov The simple example you provide seems to contain an error. The controller override the default interface method `sayHello` instead of `sayHelloImpl`. I don't think this code even compiles. But I tried what you mean and the workaround works fine ;)

Comment: @GerardBosch Yep, thank you! Gist fixed -- class overrides abstract method.

Comment: @TimurMilovanov your comment is a very complete answer. You could publish it as an answer instead of a comment as it is very valuable and provides a working workaround example for the case of Spring previous to 4.3 ;)

Comment: full support for annotations on interfaces got added recently - please see my answer below and upvote

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had the same problem. Following has worked for me:

```
public class GoalServiceImpl implements GoalService {
    ...
    public void removeGoal(@PathVariableString id) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i resolved this problem.

**ON CLIENT SIDE:**

I'm using this library https://github.com/ggeorgovassilis/spring-rest-invoker/. This library generate a proxy from interface to invoke spring rest service.

I extended this library:

I created an annotations and a factory client class:

Identify a Spring Rest Service

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface SpringRestService {
    String baseUri();
}
```

This class generates a client rest from interfaces

```
public class RestFactory implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor,EmbeddedValueResolverAware  {

    StringValueResolver resolver;

    @Override
    public void setEmbeddedValueResolver(StringValueResolver resolver) {
        this.resolver = resolver;
    }
    private String basePackage = "com";

    public void setBasePackage(String basePackage) {
        this.basePackage = basePackage;
    }


    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        createBeanProxy(beanFactory,SpringRestService.class);
        createBeanProxy(beanFactory,JaxrsRestService.class);
    }

    private void createBeanProxy(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory,Class<? extends Annotation> annotation) {
        List<Class<Object>> classes;
        try {
            classes = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotatedClasses(basePackage, annotation);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BeanInstantiationException(annotation, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory;
        for (Class<Object> classType : classes) {
            Annotation typeService = classType.getAnnotation(annotation);   
            GenericBeanDefinition beanDef = new GenericBeanDefinition();
            beanDef.setBeanClass(getQueryServiceFactory(classType, typeService));
            ConstructorArgumentValues cav = new ConstructorArgumentValues();
            cav.addIndexedArgumentValue(0, classType);
            cav.addIndexedArgumentValue(1, baseUri(classType,typeService));
            beanDef.setConstructorArgumentValues(cav);
            registry.registerBeanDefinition(classType.getName() + "Proxy", beanDef);
        }
    }

    private String baseUri(Class<Object> c,Annotation typeService){
        String baseUri = null;
        if(typeService instanceof SpringRestService){
            baseUri = ((SpringRestService)typeService).baseUri();  
        }else if(typeService instanceof JaxrsRestService){
            baseUri = ((JaxrsRestService)typeService).baseUri();
        }
        if(baseUri!=null && !baseUri.isEmpty()){
            return baseUri = resolver.resolveStringValue(baseUri);
        }else{
            throw new IllegalStateException("Impossibile individuare una baseUri per l'interface :"+c);
        }
    }

    private static Class<? extends FactoryBean<?>> getQueryServiceFactory(Class<Object> c,Annotation typeService){
        if(typeService instanceof SpringRestService){
            return it.eng.rete2i.springjsonmapper.spring.SpringRestInvokerProxyFactoryBean.class;  
        }else if(typeService instanceof JaxrsRestService){
            return it.eng.rete2i.springjsonmapper.jaxrs.JaxRsInvokerProxyFactoryBean.class;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Impossibile individuare una classe per l'interface :"+c);
    }
}
```

I configure my factory:

```
<bean class="it.eng.rete2i.springjsonmapper.factory.RestFactory">
    <property name="basePackage" value="it.giancarlo.rest.services" />
</bean>
```

**ON REST SERVICE SIGNATURE**

this is an example interface:

```
package it.giancarlo.rest.services.spring;

import ...

@SpringRestService(baseUri="${bookservice.url}")
public interface BookService{

    @Override
    @RequestMapping("/volumes")
    QueryResult findBooksByTitle(@RequestParam("q") String q);

    @Override
    @RequestMapping("/volumes/{id}")
    Item findBookById(@PathVariable("id") String id);

}
```

**ON REST SERVICE IMPLEMENTATION**

Service implementation

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("bookService")
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {
    @Override
    public QueryResult findBooksByTitle(String q) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public Item findBookById(String id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

To resolve annotation on parameters I create a custom RequestMappingHandlerMapping that looks all interfaces annotated with @SpringRestService

```
public class RestServiceRequestMappingHandlerMapping extends RequestMappingHandlerMapping{


    public HandlerMethod testCreateHandlerMethod(Object handler, Method method){
        return createHandlerMethod(handler, method);
    }

    @Override
    protected HandlerMethod createHandlerMethod(Object handler, Method method) {
        HandlerMethod handlerMethod;
        if (handler instanceof String) {
            String beanName = (String) handler;
            handlerMethod = new RestServiceHandlerMethod(beanName,getApplicationContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory(), method);
        }
        else {
            handlerMethod = new RestServiceHandlerMethod(handler, method);
        }
        return handlerMethod;
    }


    public static class RestServiceHandlerMethod extends HandlerMethod{

        private Method interfaceMethod;


        public RestServiceHandlerMethod(Object bean, Method method) {
            super(bean,method);
            changeType();
        }

        public RestServiceHandlerMethod(Object bean, String methodName, Class<?>... parameterTypes) throws NoSuchMethodException {
            super(bean,methodName,parameterTypes);
            changeType();
        }

        public RestServiceHandlerMethod(String beanName, BeanFactory beanFactory, Method method) {
            super(beanName,beanFactory,method);
            changeType();
        }


        private void changeType(){
            for(Class<?> clazz : getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getInterfaces()){
                if(clazz.isAnnotationPresent(SpringRestService.class)){
                    try{
                        interfaceMethod = clazz.getMethod(getMethod().getName(), getMethod().getParameterTypes());
                        break;      
                    }catch(NoSuchMethodException e){

                    }
                }
            }
            MethodParameter[] params = super.getMethodParameters();
            for(int i=0;i<params.length;i++){
                params[i] = new RestServiceMethodParameter(params[i]);
            }
        }




        private class RestServiceMethodParameter extends MethodParameter{

            private volatile Annotation[] parameterAnnotations;

            public RestServiceMethodParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter){
                super(methodParameter);
            }


            @Override
            public Annotation[] getParameterAnnotations() {
                if (this.parameterAnnotations == null){
                        if(RestServiceHandlerMethod.this.interfaceMethod!=null) {
                            Annotation[][] annotationArray = RestServiceHandlerMethod.this.interfaceMethod.getParameterAnnotations();
                            if (this.getParameterIndex() >= 0 && this.getParameterIndex() < annotationArray.length) {
                                this.parameterAnnotations = annotationArray[this.getParameterIndex()];
                            }
                            else {
                                this.parameterAnnotations = new Annotation[0];
                            }
                        }else{
                            this.parameterAnnotations = super.getParameterAnnotations();
                        }
                }
                return this.parameterAnnotations;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

I created a configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport{

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RestServiceRequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new RestServiceRequestMappingHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setOrder(0);
        handlerMapping.setInterceptors(getInterceptors());
        handlerMapping.setContentNegotiationManager(mvcContentNegotiationManager());

        PathMatchConfigurer configurer = getPathMatchConfigurer();
        if (configurer.isUseSuffixPatternMatch() != null) {
            handlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(configurer.isUseSuffixPatternMatch());
        }
        if (configurer.isUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch() != null) {
            handlerMapping.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(configurer.isUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch());
        }
        if (configurer.isUseTrailingSlashMatch() != null) {
            handlerMapping.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(configurer.isUseTrailingSlashMatch());
        }
        if (configurer.getPathMatcher() != null) {
            handlerMapping.setPathMatcher(configurer.getPathMatcher());
        }
        if (configurer.getUrlPathHelper() != null) {
            handlerMapping.setUrlPathHelper(configurer.getUrlPathHelper());
        }
        return handlerMapping;
    }
}
```

and I configurated it

```
<bean class="....WebConfig" />
```