# Problems trying to inherit SpringBoot REST annotations on concrete class

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to configure an Interface with some REST methods with Spring Boot. But when I implement that interface on a concrete class, the @PathVariable or @RequestParam do not work properly unless I repeat the configuration on my concrete method (which I dont want because the interface is being generated by a maven plugin). Lets take a look at the interface and the concrete class.

```
@RequestMapping("employees")
public interface EmployeesResource {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/json"})
EmployeesResource.GetEmployeesResponse getEmployees(
    @RequestParam(value = "pageNum", defaultValue = "0")
    long pageNum,
    @RequestParam(value = "pageSize", defaultValue = "10")
    long pageSize)
    throws Exception;


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "{employeeId}", produces = {
    "application/json"
})
EmployeesResource.GetEmployeesByEmployeeIdResponse getEmployeesByEmployeeId(
    @PathVariable("employeeId")
    long employeeId)
    throws Exception;
}
```

Now lets take a look at the concrete class.

```
@RestController
public class EmployeesResourceImpl implements EmployeesResource {

@Override
public EmployeesResource.GetEmployeesByEmployeeIdResponse getEmployeesByEmployeeId(long employeeId) {
    //omitted
    return EmployeesResource.GetEmployeesByEmployeeIdResponse.withJsonOK(e);
}

@Override
public EmployeesResource.GetEmployeesResponse getEmployees(long pageNum, long pageSize)
        throws Exception {
    //omitted
    return EmployeesResource.GetEmployeesResponse.withJsonOK(list);
}
}
```

When I make a call to http://127.0.0.1:8080/employees/1 it throws an exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Optional long parameter 'employeeId' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type.
```

I know that this is because me employeeId is long and not Long, but that is not the question because if I add the @PathVariable("employeeId") to the method on the concrete class, it all works.

So, what I want is to not repeat the configuration from the interface into the concrete class. Same goes for the @RequestParam(value = "pageNum", defaultValue = "0").

I have googled a lot and did not found that capacity of inheritance of annotations inside Spring Boot. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Andy Wilkinson suggested this post [Spring MVC Annotated Controller Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002514/spring-mvc-annotated-controller-interface) but the guy concluded that there is no way around this due to AOP injections that Spring does. Is there really nothing to do here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC Annotated Controller Interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002514/spring-mvc-annotated-controller-interface)

Comment: Yes Andy, he wants the same thing that I do, and he concluded that there is no way of doing that. I still wonder if there is a way. Thanks for the reply!