# Spring @RequestParam and controller interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm confused with the behavior of `@RequestParam(value="someValue")`.
In the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) it is said that

> When using controller interfaces (e.g. for AOP proxying), make sure to consistently put all your mapping annotations - such as @RequestMapping and @SessionAttributes - on the controller interface rather than on the implementation class.

If I place `@RequestParam` on my controller interface its `value` is totally ignored (and therefore mapped value is `null` if parameter name is different from the received parameter name), but `defaultValue` and `required` work ok.

If I place `@RequestParam` on my controller implementation, everything works fine.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002514/spring-mvc-annotated-controller-interface) answer, but I cannot understand why some parameters work while others don't and why docs are wrong.

Code example:

interface:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
List<MyObject> get(
     //works if parameter in request has name "userName", which is not correct
     @RequestParam(value = "username", required = false) String userName,
     @RequestParam(value = "searchValue", required = false) String searchValue,
     @RequestParam(value = "someId", required = false) Integer someId);
```

implementation:

```
@Override
public List<MyObject> get(
        String userName,
        String searchValue,
        Integer someId) {
    return myService.get(userName, searchValue, someId);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'default value and required' are recognized?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker if I write `@RequestParam(defaultValue = "username", required = false)` on my interface, the corresponding parameter always has value "username"

Answer (score 2):

This finally should be resolved: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11055?focusedCommentId=160889&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-160889

> Juergen Hoeller added a comment - Yesterday
>
> I'm happy to report that this is finally resolved in master now, in time for the 5.1 RC1 release!