# Why does Spring Boot not read the PathVariable that is defined on my interface resource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using a custom code generator to transform a REST contract in to Java interfaces. Below find a sample of a generated resource Java interface.

```
@Generated(
    date = "2018-01-30T11:56:25.156Z",
    comments = "Specification filename: country.v1.json",
    value = "GENERATOR"
)
@RequestMapping("/v1/countries")
public interface CountriesResource {

  @RequestMapping(
      method = RequestMethod.GET,
      path = "/{id}",
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
  )
  @ResponseBody
  LandGetResourceModel getEntity(@PathVariable("id") String id);
}
```

Additionally the generator creates an `@RestController` implementation a that interface for Spring to create a controller bean.

```
@RestController
public class CountriesResourceImpl implements CountriesResource {

    @Override
    public CountryGetResourceModel getEntity(String id) {
        return new CountryGetResourceModel();
    }
}
```

So far everything works fine. Spring creates the RestController bean and the HTTP calls are directed correctly to the corresponding Handler method (e.g. `getEntity`).

The problem is that for some reason Spring is not able to resolve path variables when they are defined on the interface. All calls containing a path variable are handled but the method parameter of any path variable is `null`. If I then add the `PathVariable` annotation to the implementation class Spring is able to resolve the corresponding value.

Is there a way to tell Spring to read the `PathVariable` from the interface method declaration like it does for the `RequestMapping` annotations?

Comment: yes, but seems like it won't help you. look what I've found: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11055

Comment: ..and explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/8005644/5185646

Comment: What a pitty :( Well it seems I have to generate some decorators classes for that resource Interface and then delegate the calls to the implementation class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, seems like it is a known issue. I've found [the following opened Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11055) on the question. Some explanation can be found from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8005644/5185646). Also, in [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002514/spring-mvc-annotated-controller-interface-with-pathvariable) I took the previous answer I see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39977265/5185646). However, I haven't tried it and it seems to be heavy.